# Couldn't find MySQL as service

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

My operating system is Windows 8.
Previously Xampp was installed in G:/

Then I made an user account for my friend in windows and installed Xampp for him in E:/

Then I removed Xampp from E:/

After that MySQL vanished from services list. But Apache 2.2 still exists and runs too. Whenever I try to visit localhost/phpmyadmin/

it says:

> Error MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)  Connection for controluser as
>   defined in your configuration failed.

I have checked the configuration file. All of them are ok.

Now my question is-
**Is there any way to get backups of my databases from "htdocs" ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of this is supposition, as I am a WAMP user by preference but I have used XAMPP in the past:

I think that the Install on E:\ caused the Apache and MySQL services to be installed from the E:\xampp directories, negating the G:\ installed versions.

When you uninstalled the E:\ version it should have removed both Apache and MySQL services.

If you still have the version on G:\ I seem to remember there is a way of re-installing the Apache and MySQL services so run the XAMMP icon and I think there is a button for each service, somethng like `SVC` beside the info about Apache and MySQL that tells you its running or not, and that will reinstall the services from whereever you ran the XAMPP controller from.

As to the databases you created using the E:\ version you installed, If the uninstall is written properly they will still be in the E:\XAMPP\mysql\data folder, and can be copied to your G:\XAMPP\mysql\data folder if they are MYISAM.

Assuming you didnt delete the G:\XAMPP folders from the original install, those databases should still be in G:\XAMPP\mysql\data and will become visible again when you get the MySQL service installed again

Comment: @SekanderBadsha Glad to be of assistance. Would you mind accepting the answer as coorect then, so others in this situation will see it as useful.